# Knockout - Getting clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have the following mark-up:

```
<fieldset>
   <div>
       <label class="editor-label">Question 1?</label>
       <input type="text" class="editor-field" />     
       <button type="button" data-bind="click: helpClicked">Help</button>
       <p class="help">Help 3</p>
   </div>
    <div>
       <label class="editor-label">Question 2?</label>
       <input type="text" class="editor-field" />
       <button type="button" data-bind="click: helpClicked">Help</button>
       <p class="help">Help 3</p>
   </div>
   <div>
       <label class="editor-label">Question 3?</label>
       <input type="text" class="editor-field" />
        <button type="button" data-bind="click: helpClicked">Help</button>
       <p class="help">Help 3</p>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

I want to toggle the visibility of the the `<p>` with the class `help` in the same `Div` as the clicked button.  I am trying to use $(this) to determine which button was clicked and then I could get the correct "help" element from there.

The problem is that `$(this)` isn't returning the clicked button.

At the moment I am trying to simply hide the clicked button like:

```
var viewModel = {
    helpClicked: function () {
        $(this).hide();           
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

This doesn't work.  Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here is a jsFiddle with one possible solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/unklefolk/399MF/1/

You can target the DOM elements you want via this syntax:

```
var viewModel = {     
    helpClicked: function (item, event) {   
        $(event.target).hide(); 
        $(event.target).next(".help").show()            
    } 
};  
ko.applyBindings(viewModel); ​
```

Comment: you may find you need to use `currentTarget` if you're using something like a `<button>` with nested content. the `target` will end up being the content inside the button, such as an image, span or text node.

Comment: It's always possible to find the arguments by debugging and checking the `arguments` object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: it was wrapping event.target in the $() that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 14):

Try using `event.currentTarget` followed by `next()`

```
$(event.currentTarget).next().hide();
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/FRd8L/)

Comment: This is useful - event.target will get exactly what you clicked on. Even if it's a child. currentTarget will get the element the click handler is appended to.

Comment: event.currentTarget is not available for IE8. For <= IE8 support you can use:

`var target = (event.currentTarget) ? event.currentTarget : event.srcElement;`

Answer (score 3):

Are those divs inside the fieldset built via Knockout? (they look templatey). If so, I think a more MVVMish way to approach this would be to extract the currently bound item from the button click handler and bind the visibility of each help paragraph to a view model property  set by that handler on the corresponding item, rather than doing the UI operations procedurally. At least, this is the pattern I've been moving towards and finding it much nicer (especially after doing similar things in WPF and Silverlight).

Answer (score 1):

```
This should work

var viewModel = 
{
         helpClicked: function (data,element) {
       /*
      data is the current model passed to the button
      element is the button currently interacting with
     but to get the dom object equivalent of the 
     element you've to access it          
    via its currentTarget property
    */
        $(element.currentTarget).hide();           
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```