# Knockout Offset Values

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm trying to write a function that scrolls to a list element based on this question:

[Scroll a list item such that it becomes visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644927/scroll-a-list-item-such-that-it-becomes-visible)

I had a lot of difficulty with it in my Knockout app, and I eventually discovered the reason why. Here are two Fiddles with the same goToByScroll function:

http://jsfiddle.net/CaptainLexington/tNhLa/57/

http://jsfiddle.net/CaptainLexington/5wZQ2/108/

```
function goToByScroll(selector) {
    // Scroll
    $('ul#parent').animate({
        scrollTop: $(selector).position().top
    },
        'slow');
}
```

In the first Fiddle, the HTML is hardcoded and the scroll function works fine. Hurrah!

In the second Fiddle, the list items are generated by Knockout. The scroll function's behavior is goofy. Open up the console and click on each list item and you will discover why: the jQuery.offset().top values seem to bear very little relation to where they actually are. In the hardcoded version, the offset().top values are monotonically increasing; in the Knockout version, they are either arbitrary or cyclical.

So, is there any way around this? Is this a bug in Knockout or an unfortunate but unavoidable side-effect of the implementation of their functionality? Is it worth reporting it to Knockout, or should I decide on some other feature for my app?

Comment: @Jamiec I clicked the links to both Fiddles; they both run perfectly and show jQuery as an external dependency.

Comment: I agree with Warren. There is no problem with knockout. I guess its the way you use it.

Comment: Yeah, I see they're listed - I get `TypeError: $(...).position(...) is undefined` when I click on one of the list items - that error is usually a missing jQuery. *shrug* guess im noy going to be much help here

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, and for whatever reason, I'm not getting the same error! Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: Its to do with your use of `el.toElement` - that does not exist in FF (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600174/event-toelement-in-ie8-and-firefox). You should probably use `el.target` as discussed here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391932/knockout-getting-clicked-element)

Comment: Ok, now that's fixed you're not going to like me.... unable to reproduce issue. On both your fiddles the output `top` behaves exactly the same. In my case each element's `top` increases by 20px. I suggest you have a browser-specific issue. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome. I'll test them both in FF real quick.

Comment: I do see what you mean about the animating scroll in the second one behaving a bit weird though. I also see the logged value change when you scroll the panel - but this is by design - `position()` gives the "position of an element relative to the offset parent"

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to change it to offset and see if it reproduces the behavior I was talking about. One moment.

EDIT: Nevermind, offset definitely doesn't have the behavior I want it to, which makes sense considering what it's supposed to do. I'm going to continue comparing the Chrome and FF fiddles and see if I'm the one making the error - of perception!

Answer (score 1):

This was actually my fault; a failure to understand how to interpret the offset/position  data (I was expecting it to be consistent after scrolling) I was receiving. I also managed to get the function to work exactly as expected in my original app, but I don't know how or what I would have changed to do it.